# Elimination of cycle between relationships in the proposed ER diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram

In making an ER schema for a simple database, I have encountered the following problem:

- I get a cycle in the diagram, which I don't know if it is redundant or I could eliminate it somehow.

I present the problem on a large scale:

1. The visit entity records visits to London by a vehicle. This entity contains information on their arrival, departure and total visit time.
2. The vehicle entity contains information on the vehicle's place of origin, CO2 emissions and its number plate.
3. The entity date contains information for each date of the day of the week to which it corresponds and the name of the holiday for any region added.

The region of the entity `Date` is matched to the `Vehicle` region. The entry_date/end_date of the entity `Visit` is matched to the date of the entity `Date`. Finally, the number plate of the entity `Vehicle` is matched to the number plate of the entity `Visit`. In this way, the cycle that I mentioned at the beginning appears.

The ER diagram is as follows:

[image: ER diagram of the problem]

If there are any questions about the problem that I have not explained, please do not hesitate to ask me. I welcome suggestions for improving the ER diagram, either to remove the cycle or to simply keep it as it is if you think it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents -

"Date" is really not a good name for entity or table.
First, it is too general to convey what you really refer to.
Second, it is a reserved key word in most common languages. You just cause unnecessary trouble for programming.

You use "Date" to get holiday name (for particular region) and week day, right?
My suggestion is that you only need to save holidays in this table because weekday can be figured out in most common programming language.

This "Date" table is just a lookup table to help you find out holiday, you do not need to enforce relation between "Date" and Visit

I'd also suggest you add Region table to enforce consistent naming.

Here is the DB diagram, I renamed "date" to "holiday"
[image]

Here is the SQL server implementation -

```
create table region (
  region_code varchar(100) primary key
 ,region_name varchar(100)
)

create table holiday (
  holiday_date date not null
 ,region_code varchar(100) not null
 ,holiday_name varchar(100) not null
)

alter table holiday add primary key (holiday_date, region_code)
alter table holiday add foreign key (region_code) references region (region_code)

create table vehicle (
  number_plate varchar(100) primary key
 ,region_code varchar(100) not null
 ,CO2_emission varchar(100)
)

alter table vehicle add foreign key (region_code) references region (region_code)

create table visit (
  number_plate varchar(100) not null
 ,entry_date date not null
 ,end_date date
)

alter table visit add primary key (number_plate, entry_date)
alter table visit add foreign key (number_plate) references vehicle (number_plate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Relate** relationship between **Vehicle** and **Date** entity is redundant here. You can still find the dates for each visit a vehicle completed from the existing relationships. If you convert the ER diagram to DB tables, it'll be more clear.

Why are **entry_date** and **exit_date** two attributes of the **Visit** entity? These are already considered by the many-to-2 relationship with the **Date** entity. Remove these two attributes along with **number_plate** from **Visit**. Lastly, add an unique id to the **Visit** entity.

Comment: Several questions: I don't understand why the relationship is redundant if vehicle is related to date from the region field. Regarding your second paragraph, I understand what you are saying. But I think it doesn't make much sense to add a visit code in my problem, probably visits can be defined from a joint code of number_plate and entry_date. Would that be correct?

Comment: A good ER diagram ensures that when it will be converted to DB tables, different tables will not repeat same data. Think in a simple way: `region` is an attribute of vehicle, a date cannot have `region` information. You should remove the `region` field from `Date`.
I didn't get what you meant by `visit` code. I would suggest you convert the diagram into tables (google for the rules) and check if you face any trouble to convert the diagram.

Comment: The problem is that the date, if it has a ```region``` attribute. This is because date includes information about whether the day is a public holiday for a given ```region```. This is where my initial problem arises.